# Add ethereum address to dynamic array

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am trying to add an address dynamically to an array of addresses with Solidity. However, when I run truffle test my test fails. Please see the following snippit of my test:

```
function testAddPet() public {
  address expected = this;
  address[] storage adopters;
  adopters.push(expected);

  Assert.equal(adopters[0], expected, "Cannot add new pet" );
}
```

From my understanding "address expected" returns my current address (I am running on address 0 of ganache-cli, with metamask on account 1 (not zero indexed)).
By pushing this element my expectations are that adopters[0] = expected.

This is my test result:

```
TestAdoption
✓ testUserCanAdoptPet (43ms)
✓ testGetAdopterAddressByPetId (56ms)
✓ testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray (70ms)
1) testAddPet

Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

TestEvent(result: <indexed>, message: Cannot add new pet)

---------------------------


3 passing (590ms)
1 failing

1) TestAdoption testAddPet:
   Error: Cannot add new pet
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:319138:17
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at processResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:319136:19)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

For me the test result is not really helping me why it is not working. I hope someone here understand what I do not :).

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use: address expected = address(this) and tell if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my test works. See the snippit including explanation below:

```
function testAddPet() public {
  address expected = address(this);
  address[] storage adopters;
  adopters.push(expected);

  Assert.equal(adopters[0], expected, "Incorrect adopter");
}
```

As [Muhammed Altabba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8303489/muhammad-altabba) points out "this" should be replaced to "address(this)".